# ¿Como retornar 2 valores en una función en Java?

Tags: java, poo, array

**Quisiera retornar 2 valores posFila y posColumna pero obviamente solo me 
      deja retornar un valor**

```
public static int buscarElemento(Arrelgo objeto, int valor) {
    int posColumna = -1;
    int posFila = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < objeto.getMatriz().length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < objeto.getMatriz().length; j++) {
        if (valor == objeto.getMatriz()[i][j]) {
            posFila = -i;
            posColumna = -1;
            break;

        }
    }
}
    return posFila;
}
```

Comment: Usa un arreglo o array o matriz o como se llamen. O un diccionario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para retornar dos valores desde un método en java, lo que tiene que hacer es crear un objeto que almacene esos dos valores y retornar ese objeto. Luego, del retorno puede obtener los dos valores que almacena el objeto.

**Clase Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Se obtienen los valores retornados por la funcion buscarElemento().
        System.out.println("valor 1:" + buscarElemento(objeto, 2).getPosFila());
        System.out.println("valor 2:" + buscarElemento(objeto, 4).getPosColumna());

    }

    public static Posicion buscarElemento(Arrelgo objeto, int valor) {

        // Objeto que se retorna
        Posicion posicion;

        int posColumna = -1;
        int posFila = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < objeto.getMatriz().length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < objeto.getMatriz().length; j++) {
                if (valor == objeto.getMatriz()[i][j]) {
                    posFila = -i;
                    posColumna = -1;
                    break;

                }
            }
        }

        posicion = new Posicion(posFila, posColumna);

        return posicion;
    }

}
```

**Clase Posicion**

```
public class Posicion {

    private int posFila;
    private int posColumna;

    public Posicion(int posFila, int posColumna) {
        this.posFila = posFila;
        this.posColumna = posColumna;
    }

    public int getPosFila() {
        return posFila;
    }

    public void setPosFila(int posFila) {
        this.posFila = posFila;
    }

    public int getPosColumna() {
        return posColumna;
    }

    public void setPosColumna(int posColumna) {
        this.posColumna = posColumna;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Debes retornar un **array** de enteros, para eso debes declarar la funcion con un tipo de dato `int[]` en lugar de `int` y crear un array donde almacenes tus datos el cual será retornado.
Quedaría así:

```
public static int[] buscarElemento(Arrelgo objeto, int valor) {
    int posColumna = -1;
    int posFila = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < objeto.getMatriz().length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < objeto.getMatriz().length; j++) {
        if (valor == objeto.getMatriz()[i][j]) {
            posFila = -i;
            posColumna = -1;
            break;

        }
    }
}
    int[] posFilaColumna = {posFila, posColumna};    

    return posFilaColumna;
}
```

Y para recuperar los datos debes hacerlo lo haces asi `buscarElemento(Arrelgo objeto, int valor)[0]` para filas y `buscarElemento(Arrelgo objeto, int valor)[1]` para columna.

Comment: Mientras que sí responde a la pregunta, es un mal diseño de método =\

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar los records de java. Estos records son clases especializadas en almacenar varios campos de informacion, piensalo como una tarjeta de identificacion.

Un ejemplo de esto es en este programa que he estado haciendo de manejo de archivos:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public record SortedFiles(ArrayList<Zipped> a, ArrayList<Unzipped> b) {}
```

En este record almaceno una lista de archivos comprimidos y una lista de archivos descomprimidos. Esto lo utilizo para la siguiente funcion:

```
public static SortedFiles getAorderfiles(String path) {
    ArrayList<Zipped> ZFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Unzipped> UFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    getFoldersFiles(Paths.get(path)).forEach(File -> {
        if(File.endsWith(".ziped")){
            try{
                ZFiles.add(new Zipped(File));
            }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
                System.out.println("Archivo no se encuentra");
            }
        }else{
            try{
                UFiles.add(new Unzipped(File));
            }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
                System.out.println("Archivo no se encuentra");
            }
        }
    });
    return new SortedFiles(ZFiles, UFiles);
}
```

Como puedes ver, con esto puedo hacer que la funcion retorne dos valores sin problema alguno.

```
SortedFiles Files = getAorderfiles("Fileproves");
ZippedThread decompress = new ZippedThread(new ArrayList<Zipped>(Files.a()));
UnzippedThread compress = new UnzippedThread(new ArrayList<Unzipped>(Files.b()));
```

Además, los records crean de manera automática los getters y los toString de la clase.

Dato importante, los Records solo se deben usar para almacenar constantes, ya que no puedes usar setters con este tipo de clases.

Comment: No estás demás mencionar que `record` está disponible desde Java 14.

Comment: Buen aporte, gracias.